# New Row Button changes fixed Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've build a weight tracker with Google Sheet. I generated a button which creates a new line:

```
function addRow() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = ss.getActiveRange();
var R = range.getRowIndex();

sheet.insertRowsBefore(5, 1);
}
```

Another cell gets values from on of the rows below 5. Every time I click on the button a new line is generated but although I've added $ to the cell which should be fixed, it always increases the number +1.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Another cell gets values from on of the rows below 5. Every time I click on the button a new line is generated but although I've added $ to the cell which should be fixed, it always increases the number +1.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it always increases the number +1"? It would be helpful to see your spreadsheet (or a similar example)

Comment: @PhilAnderson if the answer actually worked for you (or at least contributed in finding the right solution), don't forget to upvote . By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved using the info provided in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the behavior you are describing seems to be expected as this also happens if you try to just add a row from the sheets UI however the good news is that you are already using apps script to add the row so you could just add an extra row and make the cell you want keep the same values like so:

```js
function addRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rownum = ss.getRange("A1").getValue(); // Value where the row number is currently
  ss.insertRowBefore(5); // Inserting a new row above row 5
  rownum = rownum + 1; // adding the amount of rows added to what is going to be the new row value
  ss.getRange("A1").setValue(rownum); // Storing the value of the row number on a cell, 
  //please make sure to change the cell number to the one most convenient to you.
  ss.getRange("E" + rownum).setValue("=B1") //Setting the formula or values you need on the cell.
  //Make sure to write the entire formula as you would on sheets between the quotations in .setValue("")
}
```

The downside here is that you need to have a cell store the new row number value but maybe you could:

1. Hide the column so the cell does not show
2. Change the color of the value to white and [protect the cell](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cprotect-a-range-or-sheet)

Alternatively you could also change the referenced cell to a hidden sheet or even an entirely different spreadsheet, the important thing here is that we need to make sure the value is stored somewhere.

I hope you find this useful and if you'd like to have an example of how to call a hidden sheet or a different spreadsheet please let me know which one you'd prefer and I will update this answer to include that option.